# Is Microsoft BizSpark a good deal for startups?

Tags: msdn, bizspark

I learned about [Microsoft BizSpark](http://www.microsoft.com/bizspark/) the other day and started the sign up process.  Has anyone else heard about it or had success with it?

Comment: We really focus on programming questions here, Barrett.

Comment: I see a lot more than just programming questions here. Plus, this relates to software development since it is a program for startups to get started with MSDN.

Comment: There is heaps of questions like this. Doesn't that interest justify the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't speak for BizSpark specifically (it's so new), but Microsoft has had the similar [Empower](http://www.empowerforisv.com/) program in place for 5 or so years. When our company was originally getting started, we joined the program (and participated for two years) and it was an excellent program.

The main benefit, of course, is that you get access to MSDN Subscriptions at such a low cost. Aside from that, though, it put us in touch with the local Microsoft office and gave us a clear path to working toward the typical ISV Partner relationship. You also get some technical support incidents, which are handy when/if you need to escalate an issue you're running into.

The requirements for Empower were/are pretty straightforward... basically commit to releasing a commercial software product based on the current Microsoft stack within two years.

Hope that helps... I look forward to hearing more about how BizSpark is different - or if it's simply the next evolution of Empower.

Comment: Good answer, need to check it out!

Answer (score 4):

Well I have just signed up... yes of course there is an "end game" amount to pay.. but if you were going to use Microsoft technologies anyway.. then it's an awesome deal.. I have the software now (today), and there is everything I need to develop the project I am working on...  Open source is excellent, don't get me wrong.. but you have to decide for the right reasons...

Answer (score 3):

I think it is a great initiative, they are giving away the highest (most expensive) licenses of Visual Studio and VS Team System. With Empower you get Visual Studio Professional Edition with MSDN.
It is important to point out that this is NOT intended for consultatnts, there is a seperate program called Microsoft Action Pack Subscription that is more geared toward that audience. The Bizspark program is for software vendors, I suppouse it will have some kind of requirement similar to what Empower had, where you have to release commercial software within certain time period. 
Let us know how your enrollment goes...

Answer (score 0):

I joined it and empower recently.  I think it is a great deal.  I had an old MSDN set of software I was using and wasn't relishing the thought of spending all that money for my startup that has no current revenue.

Apparently MS really wants to get back to enticing developers to its platform.

One of the downsides I could see (or upsides depending on your view) [and this requires a health cynicism] is that MS uses this program to

- identify potential markets for it to jump into and trounce the competition
- identify startups it wants to purchase.

It has all your information in its database - the type of business, etc.

I still joined - no big deal, but for those who already think MS if the big bad wolf this might rub them the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I think BizSpark is a great opportunity for startups which either

- know they will use Microsoft technology
- doesn't know what technology to use

The ones who doesn't know which software tools or programming language to use can test the Microsoft ones along with Open Source or other freely or inexpensive alternatives.

This way they can choose the technologies which suit them best - also when it comes to expenses for licenses - and remember to calculate the time you use to manage the licenses too.

The most enjoyable greetings
Claus Agerskov, SALDI - the Danish Open Source ERP

Answer (score -1):

My $0.02 is that it's a trap.  MS knows that many startups, especially the ones without venture capital (which in my book makes them "real" startups), are flocking to open source technologies both because of the cost savings and the control over your destiny -- the ability to fix bugs, modify things, and prevent vendor lockin that are the best parts of open source.  MS is trying to trick them into becoming locked in.  I'd steer clear.  But I'd also steer clear of venture capital for similar reasons.  IMHO, a startup that is going to actually go places (more than just being acquired and becoming a money sink like most bubble companies) is founded by a small group of knowledgeable people and funded out of those people's own pockets.  Doing what you love because you want to, not because you're getting rich at it is why they have the drive to succeed and innovate that bigger companies don't have.

Comment: Sometimes a start-up requires too much capital outlay to self-fund.  Sometimes an opportunity to capture big market share is fleeting and requires a "big and fast" approach, especially if you have a $1B idea.  But sometimes, yes, bootstrapping is the right answer.

Comment: how is it a trap?  You are free to stop using the stuff any time.  If you are successful, it is easy to pay the license fees.  If not, you just get out of the business.